# How to use multiple triggers in CSS?

Tags: css

This is my CSS code, only the Icon is rotating but the fade animation of that rectangle is not working while hovering that circle.

this is video link [Video](https://1drv.ms/v/s!AsrHS57YPlM34AHvZdXxiTWD8RUZ?e=3M13kV)

[image]

This is the image of the code above.
I want to add fade animation to the tooltip and rotation animation to the icon on hovering that button.

```
#Account-Icon:hover > #user-logo {
    animation: settingRole 2s;
}

#Account-Icon:hover > #popup { //can I use #Account-Icon:hover twice??
    animation: opacity 2s;
}

@keyframes opacity {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

> I want to add two actions when hovering over that circle
> 1.fade animation in the popup(in rectangle)
> 2.rotation of setting icon

Comment: Provide more code to create a minimal demonstration please. All you got is some css, how will anyone ever know what your html looks like

Comment: its just two divs

Comment: Yes but no one knows that but you, as you can see your provided code does not really output anything, please add the generated code so we can actually see what's going on

Comment: ok I added the snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can run multiple `:hover` declarations on the same element.
I am guessing that the pop up is not a direct child of the `#Account-Icon` if it isn't working for you.

```css
#Account-Icon:hover #user-logo {
    color: red;
}

#Account-Icon:hover #popup {
    color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="Account-Icon">
    <div id="user-logo">
        logo
    </div>
    <div id="popup">
        pop up
    </div>
</div>
```